# File Explorer for HTC Desire X - too many permissions asked for?

Tags: file-system, permissions, file-management

I have a HTC Desire X running Android 4.0.4 (not rooted)

I am looking for a file explorer mainly for 2 things
- Just browsing around the file system
- Copying an apk from my PC and executing it.

I went to Play Store to install ES File Explorer. It asks for the following permissions

- Storage
- Phone Calls
- Network Communication
- System Tools
- Hardware Contols

I have no idea why a file explorer needs so much permissions.

Are there any decent file explorers which make do with a minimum set of permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ES Datei Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ES-Datei-Explorer/com.estrongs.android.pop) is more than just a simple file explorer. It offers a bunch of additional features, which explain most of the permissions you've listed. I'm using this app for years already and can assure you: it never abused any of the permissions (especially I never saw it making "phone calls", and yes, I supervise such things).

But for the things you list:

- **Storage:** What do you thing where your files are, um, *stored*? All file managers access the "storage". Otherwise they couldn't write there, so you could not copy/move files.
- **Phone Calls:** This is a *Permission Group*, not the permission `COST_CALL` itself. The only permission from that group which *ES File* accesses is *read phone status and identity*. So it can detect whether there is an incoming/outgoing/ongoing call (and see the remote number), as well as check your device's ID (IMSI). Not sure what for the app needs this, though.
- **Network Communication:** This app can also access the network (feature list: *Remote File Manager*). So you can e.g. use it to copy files from/to your computer, e.g. using Windows Shares (also known as Samba, SMB, CIFS). A feature I really enjoy quite often. So nothing bad about this!
- **System Tools:** Again a permission group. Here the app requests: *modify system settings, connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi, set wallpaper, install shortcuts, uninstall shortcuts, access Bluetooth settings, prevent phone from sleeping*. All mentioned permissions are explainable from the app's feature list, though the "modify system settings* is a little unclear.
- **Hardware Controls:** Once more a permission group. Only used permission here is *control vibration*. So no danger from that, either.

So the point is to look behind those "Permission Groups" what permissions are really requested by an app, and cross-check that with its features. If something's unclear: ask, as you did :) "Better save than sorry" is a good attitude!

If you're still concerned, and rather want a more minimalistic solution (as you don't need all those features), there are plenty alternatives. But I personally can warmly recommend you this app, from my own experience: It's easy to use, and never let me down in years. No "permission abuse" either.